# Switch symbol: Which line is normally-closed?

Tags: schematics, diagram, symbol

The symbol below is for the component [TL32P0](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/indexer.php?file=DSASW00117094.pdf&dir=Datasheets-SW6&keywords=TL46MW&database=user-highscore#) (TINY SWITCH ON - MON), included in EAGLE 6.5.

*In this symbol, which pin is normally-closed (NC)? 1 or 3?*

*Or is the symbol not a typical one, i.e. not somehow standardized?*

[image: Screenshot from EAGLE]

Comment: It looks like pin 1 but I'd check the data sheet to make sure.

Comment: @LeonHeller That symbol is not in the datasheet (which BTW is linked). Anyhow, my question is about the symbol, which I hope is standardized. Or isn't it?

Comment: Why the down vote? This time I had a data sheet link right from the start.

Comment: Downvote made no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol in your question usually indicates the state when the push button is not pushed, when it is not being touched. The little arrow in the symbol indicates there is a spring pushing the switch contact up to the top position. When you push the lever, it pops back when you release it. That is the `ON-MOM` part in the datasheet.

Answer (score 6):

For momentary NC/NO switches, the one shown closed, is the one that should be normally closed. Convention follows common sense.

The given switch though, is a on/on SPDT switch. It isn't really a NC/NO momentary switch, so there is no concept of "normally closed" aside from it being the side you want. If only one throw of a SPDT switch is used, the symbol should match that side, but that's not very necessary in most cases.

Comment: Thanks! I was also considering the opposite, i.e. that the arrow shows the direction in which to push.

Comment: @feklee updated. Your switch isnt a NC/NO switch, those are momentary.

Comment: Actually the switch was just an example, I don't even use it. Note that in the EAGLE description and in the data sheet it says "ON - MON" for the TL32P0.

Comment: @feklee the diagram and the language confused me. A different sheet confirms that it is On/Momentary. In that case, pin 1 is supposed to be Momentary, Pin 3 is On... So the symbol shows the non-obvious connection. Hmm..

Comment: Sorry about the language of the datasheet. I simply used the one linked from the EAGLE library, and that is in German. I now linked to an English version provided by a third party (couldn't find information about the switch on the [manufacturer's site](http://www.apem.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the tables in the data sheet, the switch configurations are given in tables that have roman numeral column headings.

```
                       III  II  I
Einpolig Zweipolig
TL36P0 TL46P0          ON   -   ON
TL39P0 TL49P0          ON   OFF ON
[ ... ]
TL32P0 TL42P0          ON   -   MOM
```

I would think that for the single pole part, the roman numerals correspond to the pin numbers, and are given as roman numerals in order to convey the idea that these are positions and not pin numberings. (The two-pole parts have six contacts, and so perhaps I, II and III correspond to 1 and 4, 2 and 5, and 3 and 6).

I'd get my hands on a sample before designing a PCB.

For the vertically mounted units, it doesn't matter; you can just design the PCB arbitrarily and then determine their orientation when stuffing the board, since the footprint is symmetric, but the ones that lie horizontally, with bent terminals, have to be correct.

**Now, on to the symbol.** I would say that the normally closed contact of the switch is the one that is actually symbolized as being closed. With that in mind, if the roman numerals in the data sheet correspond to pin numbers (positions III, II, I being pins 3, 2, 1), the symbol's pin numbering is then reversed relative to the data sheet.

In this kind of situation, one way out is to get your hands on a sample of the part, then clone the symbol and renumber the pins, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I am actually using a different switch, which I desoldered from an old Logitech mouse. Only it didn't exist in EAGLE, and so I decided to create my own library for it. For that I copied the symbol from the TL32P0.